# Release method was gone in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I had downloaded a Xcode 4.2.1 for lion a few days ago.

But strangely, when I try to use the release method in instance variable,

Error message appears as shown below.

What is the reason for the error message?

How do I resolve the error message can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a project with Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) turned on.  It does the retaining and releasing for you, and you're not allowed to mess it up by trying to do it yourself.  This is a **good** thing.

[Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html)
[Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is because Xcode 4.2.1 is using the iOS 5 SDK, which implements a new concept called ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). This is meant to make life easier by preventing developers from having to worry about when and where to release their objects. Instead it releases them for you in the most optimal way when they are no longer needed. As a result, the "release" method has been removed.